# Derivative of a path.

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Define path: $s(t)= \langle 0,\cos(t),\sin(t)\rangle$

We are given that it is on the surface of $F(x,y,z)= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 -1$

Am told to find $s'(t)$ and a given point $t = (\pi/2)$.

Is $s'(t) = F(s(t))'$?

Comment: You're problem statement isn't clear enough.  For instance how is $s(t)$ "on the surface $F$"?

Comment: F(s(t)) = 0 means that the path s(t) is on the surface defined by F(x,y,z).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$s'(t)=\langle0,-\sin(t),\cos(t)\rangle$, so $s'(\frac{\pi}{2})=\langle0,-1,0\rangle$. It doesn't matter that the path is on the surface. In fact $F(s(t))'=\frac{\mathbb{d}}{\mathbb dt}(\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)-1)=\frac{\mathbb{d}}{\mathbb dt}(0)=0$ for all $t$.

Comment: >"It doesn't matter that the path is on the surface" Thanks for that.